# Map not moving to desired location after animateCamera with MyLocation enabled

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

My app is having this problem with some devices only and have not been able to find what is causing it.

My MainActivy has a MapFragment, and this MainActivity lets the user open a SearchActivity to look for an address which is returned to the MainActivity as coordinates. The problem is that on some devices the animateCamera is not working, I mean, the map keeps at the current GPS location.

I've been able to reproduce this on Galaxy SII (Android 4.1) and LG (Android 4.0), however in my Galaxy SIII LTE (Android 4.4) it works fine.

Here is some parts of my code:

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SearchRequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Double latitude = data.getDoubleExtra(SearchActivity.LATITUDE, 0);
        Double longitude = data.getDoubleExtra(SearchActivity.LONGITUDE, 0);

        if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
            ((MapFragment) mFragment).setMapLocation(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
}

    public void setMapLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
        CameraPosition newPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .zoom(15.5f).build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newPosition));
    }
```

SearchActivity (How the data is returned to the MainActivity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(LATITUDE, addressListItem.getLatitude());
intent.putExtra(LONGITUDE, addressListItem.getLongitude());
intent.putExtra(ADDRESS, addressListItem.getLocation() + " - " + ddressListItem.getDetail());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

Comment: Especially with animation I had sometimes the effect, that the animation was stopped by another event, before the animation could finish. So I would try to use moveCamera instead, just to check, whether it still does not work on some devices. If this helps, you should check (e.g. by logging), whether closing your search dialog imposes some touch event which is still recognized by the map (just a wild guess).